# ContentPresenter in ItemControl.ItemTemplate to show displaymemberpath of itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, contentpresenter

I want to know is there anyway to put contentpresenter in itemtemplate of an itemscontrol to display my data. I don't want hard code binding like Text="{Binding username}" cause I am building a custom control, I think ContentPresenter is what I want. But after I tried using contentpresenter, it give me stackoverflowexception.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=listbox}" DisplayMemberPath={Binding DisplayMemberPath}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Separator" Text=", "/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding username}"/>-->
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

That's my code. 
If without those seperator and itemtemplate, I able to display my data by just using the displaymemberpath, but it stack all the name together. I still finding any solution to solve it. I hope you can provide some ideas to do this.

Comment: If you check the visual tree that is generated when using an ItemsControl, you'll see it is already creating a ContentPresenter for each item. The ContentPresenter renders what you put on the ItemTemplate, so if you put another ContentPresenter inside, it'll try to generate infinite representations... And hence the StackOverflowException.

Comment: There's no trivial way to do this. You could use a MultiValueConverter inside your ItemTemplate's TextBlock Binding, using your VM's DisplayMemberPath property and Reflection to return the correct value (and even add the comma). Or create your own custom ItemsControl... Either way, you'll have to code a tad more :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an easier way to solve this problem by using horizontal listbox. Thanks for responses

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, you can't. A [`ContentPresenter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx) is supposed to be used in a `ControlTemplate`, not a `DataTemplate`, so it is *not* the right control to use. From the linked page on MSDN:

> You typically use the `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate` of a `ContentControl` to specify where the content is to be added.

What you can do alternatively, is to declare a number of `DataTemplate`s in a `Resources` section (complete with `Binding Path`s) for different types of data and omit the `x:Key` directives, eg. do *not* name them. Also, do *not* specify one for the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`.

When doing this, WPF will implicitly select the correct `DataTemplate` for the relevant data type and so you can have different outputs for different data types. See the *The DataType Property* section of the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further explanation of this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it works well. Outside of a ContentControl's template, you must bind the Content by hand:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding username}"/>
```

I do this a great deal and it never misbehaves. ContentPresenter seems to be implemented for general use. I wonder if the API docs overstate its relationship to ContentControl.